# Why does Android Studio throw away my Code Style settings?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to write an Android app in Java. In Android Studio, I go to

> File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java

Then for Project, I modify the curly braces (I can't read code with unaligned curly braces), click apply, and finally click OK.

But then I reopen the settings to find that my settings have been discarded and it has reverted my code style.

How do I prevent it from reformatting to a different style?

Comment: " This is why I hate computers." - We can't help you with that part. What version of AS are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I undestand properly your question but I think that you want to put "Braces" in the next line, isn't it?

You must edit at:

> File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java

Then,

> Select Project or Default -> Wrapping and Braces -> Braces Placement -> NextLine

Let me know if works?
For me, it is working fine:

[image]

Comment: I thought I could just edit the code window I saw.  I never activated the "Wrapping and Braces" tab.  Trying to now, but the Apply button never lights up so I can't apply.

Comment: First time, I edit directly too :)... Then, I discovered that you must edit Wrapping and Braces tab...

Comment: Ok, I am starting to figure out how to control it.  You have to use the check boxes.  Argh.  WTF does it let you even edit the code it presents?  Anywas, thank you for providing a correct answer to my question (I still hate computers, though).

Comment: I'm glad I could help you

Comment: Started a new project and settings are reverted.  Tried to do "Export" settings from my first project but can't figure out how to import in to the new project.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you set that configuration, you can apply it for "project" or for default... If you don't find how do import, make the settings but select "default"...

Comment: You can find at: File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java->Scheme: Default!